# cs50 pset7 13.sql - remove kevin from results

Tags: cs50

UPDATE: I was able to easily and simply solve this problem by changing 2 things:

1. Add to the end of the code:
   `AND people.name != "Kevin Bacon"`
2. Change nested query to movies.id instead of title.

Thanks to this thread for the answer: [CS50 Pset 7 13.sql, I can't solve it, nested sqlite3 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60731243/cs50-pset-7-13-sql-i-cant-solve-it-nested-sqlite3-database)

I'm at the very last step of PSET7 movies (https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/7/movies/)
The goal output should be all people that have starred in a movie with Kevin, but Kevin himself should NOT be included.

I have a query that returns a list of all the names of people who starred in movies with Kevin Bacon, but Kevin is there.
How can I remove him from the results easily?
I've looked into NOT IN, but I can't figure out how to get that to work with nested queries the way I have set this up. So any advice is greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT people.name
FROM people
INNER JOIN stars ON stars.person_id = people.id
INNER JOIN movies ON movies.id = stars.movie_id
WHERE movies.title IN (
SELECT DISTINCT movies.title
FROM movies
INNER JOIN stars ON stars.movie_id = movies.id
INNER JOIN people ON people.id = stars.person_id
WHERE people.name = "Kevin Bacon" AND people.birth = "1958");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```sql
SELECT name 
FROM   people 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT DISTINCT person_id 
              FROM   stars 
              WHERE  movie_id IN (SELECT movie_id 
                                  FROM   stars 
                                         INNER JOIN people 
                                                 ON stars.person_id = people.id 
                                  WHERE  people.name = "kevin bacon" 
                                         AND people.birth = 1958)) 
       AND NOT ( name = "kevin bacon" 
                 AND birth = 1958 );
```

Explanation-

- First `SELECT` all `movie_id`s where "kevin bacon" (the one who was born in 1958) has starred
- Now `SELECT` all `person_id`s who've starred in the aforementioned movies
- Now `SELECT` the names of all these people
- Finally, exclude only "kevin bacon" (the one who was born in 1958) from this result

Comment: Thanks for the support, Chase! Your solution is much cleaner than mine.
I see how you didn't actually link movies, just used the movie id from stars. Smart!